# The post method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: get, head Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to develop uploading of the files for a user account. And each time it's submitting I get the error: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

But it Should support method Post?

Can you help, please?

```
<form  action="{{url('image-upload')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
     @csrf
     <input type="file" name="file">
     <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ImageUploadController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Application|Factory|View
     */
    public function imageUpload()
    {
        return view('imageUpload');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    public function imageUploadPost(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $request->validate([
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();

        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);

        return back()
            ->with('success','You have successfully upload image.')
            ->with('image',$imageName);

    }
}
```

**Routes, web.php** :

```
    Route::get('image-upload', 'ImageUploadController@imageUpaload')->name('image.upload');
    Route::post('image-upload', 'ImageUploadController@imageUploadPost')->name('image.upload.post');
```

Comment: You don't need to change the blade code, the problem is caused by the cache , just run `php artisan route:clear` to get rid of this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your form, you are using the route with the GET method instead of the route with the POST method. You are also using the function url instead of route. And instead of `image-upload` it should be `image.upload` with a dot `.`

So, you should change `action="{{url('image-upload')}}"` to `action="{{route('image.upload.post')}}"`

This is how your form should look like:

```
<form action="{{route('image.upload.post')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
     @csrf
     <input type="file" name="file">
     <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Try doing `php artisan route:clear` to clear the route cache and then try again.

Comment: I have this Route [image-upload.post] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\new_web\new_web\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Comment: ``{{ route('image.upload.post') }}`` use your route name with dots. :)

Comment: @Takachi Edited the answer to reflect that

Comment: Great! Thank you. Now I don't have the error, but that form doesn't upload the file, just refresh the page, and that's it..

Comment: I'm afraid your question is very unformulated and incomplete as it is. The problem you are facing now is a different question and totally doesn't match the title.

Comment: @YanaTaranets - You're likely running into validation failures. Try outputting ALL `@error` messages somewhere on your form page to diagnose.